# Nvidia 820M operating in a high temperature

Tags: nvidia, overheating, temperature

**Laptop**: DELL Inspiron 3000 Series I14-3442-A40 (Core i5)

**GPU**: Nvidia 820M (2GB 64 bits)

**Ubuntu**: 14.04 - 64 bits

**Nvidia Driver**: 331.38

**Problem**: My GPU temperature is reaching 90-93 degrees Celsius (°C) and the fan is always operating in the maximum rpm

If I change to the Intel integrated graphics the problem doesn't happen and the processor operates in 62 degrees Celsius (°C)

Could you help me with this issue, please?

There is a bug opened for this problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1391422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the answer from one of the developers to your bug report on launchpad and upload the necessary data there...

There is nothing more you can do except give the developers more data to analyse and when they change the bug status to "released", you *should* get an update through the normal Ubuntu update system after that.

*Be patient though:* I've been waiting for an update for another "released" bug for 2 months now...  ;-)